# How to find the value changes in datagridview using C#

Tags: c#

If entries are made in gridview then alert message "Please save the records".. If no entries are made, then it is not necessary to show the message. Just close the screen.

Comment: Did you try anything, code? Have you done any research as mentioned in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ?

Comment: No.If I change and entry any records in datagridview then I will save the record and then close the form.If I forget to save the record and then close the form give the message please save the record.If I don't change any values in datagridview .A message box should not display.but now message box appear please save the record while saving.

Comment: Both times you wrote _If no entries are made_, please explain correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use databinding to bind a list of objects to your datagrid. These objects should be of a type that implements the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) interface and the list's type should implement the [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, listening to the `PropertyChanged` events of its items. You can then listen to the `CollectionChanged` event of the list and flag it as dirty when it changes.

Comment: Thank for your answer.How to write the code in the formclosing event.

Comment: Once you have changed the value of the dirty flag, you can evaluate it in the `FormClosing` event.